# Visual Studio Code Will Not Format CSS Document

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, formatting

When editing HTML with VSCode in Windows 10, The right-click context menu offers to "Format Document". But not when editing a CSS document. How do I format CSS documents?

Comment: try formatting extensions such as "Prettier" in the extensions store the good thing is you can configure it easily the way you want. Prettier is very good at formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=aeschli.vscode-css-formatter
It just adds the functionality to format .css files and the shortcut stays the same Alt+Shift+F.